# Simple colored shapes in Cocos2d JS 2.2.1

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I'm trying to make simple colored shapes (rectangle, circle, and triangle) in Cocos2d in JavaScript. I'm using version 2.2.1, because I followed a tutorial that used that version. I'm trying to follow the [documentation](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/api-ref/js/V2.2.1/) but I can't figure out what constructor / function to use. Any suggestions?

```
var rectangle = new cc.ctor();
rectangle.drawSolidRect(cc.Point(10,10), cc.Point(20,20), cc.Color4F(0.5,0.2,0.1,1.0));
this.addChild(rectangle)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is a good idea to follow this tutorial. Version 2.2.1 is very old. We are using cocos2d in our projects. We started with a 2.x version and we adapted our projects to new cocos2d versions as they where launched. I know that at the moment there is a lack of tutorials and docs for cocos2d-js. I think is the less used part of cocos2d, and it is a little bit abandoned.

I think it would be a better idea to download a 3.x version of the framework and analyze the examples that come with it. IMHO, this and the API (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/api-ref/js/v3x/) are the best two references you can find to help you develop a cocos2d-js project.

However, I would suggest that you look for a more documented alternative. We've been using cocos2d for years, and we are happy enough with it, but if I had to start a project right now, I don't know whether I would choose another framework.

In cocos2d v3.X, your rectangle would be drawn like this (I changed the colour):

```
var dn = new cc.DrawNode();
    this.addChild(dn);
    dn.drawRect(cc.p(10,10), cc.p(20,20),  cc.color(249,255,115), 100,  cc.color(249,255,115));
```

And you have the API doc for DrawNode here: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/api-ref/js/v3x/symbols/cc.DrawNode.html

> ***drawRect(origin, destination, fillColor, lineWidth, lineColor)***